# Vue NuxtJS custom image tag not loading my src

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxtjs

I want to create a custom image component in NuxtJS (to pass rgb color and it automatically colorize the image), but I dont get it working that it loads my image when the img in my CustomImage Component get the path passed.

Error:

```
logotext.png:1 GET http://localhost:8080/@/assets/images/logotext.png 404 (Not 
Found)
```

My CustomImage:

```
<template>
  <img  :src="src" :alt="alt" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component, Prop } from 'nuxt-property-decorator';

@Component({})
export default class CustomImage extends Vue {
  @Prop({
    type: String,
    required: true,
  })
  public src!: string;
  @Prop({
    type: String,
    required: true,
  })
  public alt!: string;
}
</script>
```

Comment: how are you defining and passing the src url?

Comment: <CustomImage src="@/assets/images/logotext.png" alt="Logo" />

Comment: Try `<CustomImage src="~/assets/images/logotext.png" alt="Logo" />` if that doesn't work, move the images to images folder in `static` directory and  use it like `<CustomImage src="/images/logotext.png" alt="Logo" />`

Comment: Thank you. The solution with the static folder worked for me!

Comment: Ok i will posy it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a folder called `images` inside the `static` directory and move your images into it, then use them as follows :

```
 <CustomImage src="/images/logotext.png" alt="Logo" />
```

the `/` refers to static directory.

check [this](http://boussadjra.github.io/vue-pro-sidebar) for more details